# Fixed position won't do in different browser, how to make a table with columns in Ext.Panel?

Tags: css, extjs, layout, cross-browser, slider

I'm trying to figure how to show a menu on two different browser. Right now, it's perfect using fixed position on Chrome (fixed only for a small Ext Panel, not all the page don't worry).

The problem is that it won't show correctly in FireFox (the sliders are too bug in FireFox). I tried to make them float:right, but it's not working at all. The 1st one is perfect, and the other ones are not making any sense at all.

I tried using a table but I can't seem to understand this technique. I've made a 2 colomns table and it's not that at all that I have.

This is a picture of the panel on Linux (left) and Chrome (right). The panel is the one with the sliders in it. You can see that on FireFox, the sliders are too long as I'm using fixed positionning right now.

[image: FireFox is Left, Chrome is right, see the sliders...]

Would you have an idea for me? Is table layout a good idea? Should I simply lower the width of the sliders a little to make them fit both? Is there a way?

Or mayve it would be better to ask: Is there a way to ask my large left panel (all the left stuff) to make sure everything fits in there? Because if I open the page full screen, the left panel is the correct size and there are no problems at all even after I resize smaller...

Thanks a lot guys.

PS: This is the code (all of it) of my panel (it's indented a lot, see it at the right side):

```
new Ext.Panel({
                                                                                                title: '<center>' + extjs_gui_products_tab + '</center>',
                                                                                                id: 'products_tab',
                                                                                                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                                                                                                padding: 3,
                                                                                                cls: 'ProductLabel', 
                                                                                                items: [  

                                                                                                            //TOFINISH
                                                                                                            new Ext.Slider({
                                                                                                                                        width: 125,
                                                                                                                                        value: 73,
                                                                                                                                        listeners: {
                                                                                                                                            change: function(analysesSlider, val) {
                                                                                                                                                map.getLayersByName(openlayers_wms_layer_analyses)[0].setOpacity(val/100);
                                                                                                                                         }},
                                                                                                                                        style: 'position:absolute; left:135px;'
                                                                                                                                        }),                                                             
                                                                                                            new Ext.form.Checkbox({
                                                                                                                                        title: extjs_gui_products_analyses_checkbox_title,
                                                                                                                                        id: 'analyses_checkbox_extjs',
                                                                                                                                        boxLabel: extjs_gui_products_analyses_checkbox_label,
                                                                                                                                        inputValue: extjs_gui_products_analyses_checkbox_label,
                                                                                                                                        listeners: {
                                                                                                                                            check: addAnalyseLayer
                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                    }),
                                                                                                            new GeoExt.LayerOpacitySlider({
                                                                                                                                            width: 125,
                                                                                                                                            value: 73,
                                                                                                                                            layer: map.getLayersByName(openlayers_vector_layer_observations)[0],
                                                                                                                                            aggressive: true, 
                                                                                                                                            style: 'position:absolute; left:135px;'
                                                                                                                                        }),   

                                                                                                            new Ext.form.Checkbox({
                                                                                                                                        title: extjs_gui_products_observations_checkbox_title,
                                                                                                                                        id: 'observations_checkbox_extjs',
                                                                                                                                        boxLabel: extjs_gui_products_observations_checkbox_label,
                                                                                                                                        inputValue: extjs_gui_products_observations_checkbox_label,
                                                                                                                                        listeners: {
                                                                                                                                            check: loadGeoJSON
                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                    }),";

                                                                                                        //this condition controls whether or not the radar button is included in the javascript of the GUI
                                                                                                        if($radarButton==="true"){
                                                                                                                                echo "
                                                                                                                                //TOFINISH
                                                                                                                                new Ext.Slider({
                                                                                                                                        width: 125,
                                                                                                                                        value: 73,
                                                                                                                                        listeners: {
                                                                                                                                            change: function(radarSlider, val) {
                                                                                                                                                map.getLayersByName(openlayers_wms_layer_radar)[0].setOpacity(val/100);
                                                                                                                                         }},
                                                                                                                                        style: 'position:absolute; left:135px;'
                                                                                                                                        }),  
                                                                                                                                new Ext.form.Checkbox({
                                                                                                                                                            title: extjs_gui_products_radar_checkbox_title,
                                                                                                                                                            id: 'radar_composite_checkbox_extjs',
                                                                                                                                                            boxLabel: extjs_gui_products_radar_checkbox_label,
                                                                                                                                                            inputValue: extjs_gui_products_radar_checkbox_label,
                                                                                                                                                            listeners: {
                                                                                                                                                                check: addRadarLayer
                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                        }),";
                                                                                                        }
                                                //this condition controls whether or not the radar button is included in the javascript of the GUI
                                                if($forecastButton==="true"){
                                                                                echo "                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                            //TOFINISH
                                                                                                            new Ext.Slider({
                                                                                                                                        width: 125,
                                                                                                                                        value: 73,
                                                                                                                                        listeners: {
                                                                                                                                            change: function(forecastSlider, val) {
                                                                                                                                                map.getLayersByName(openlayers_wms_layer_forecast)[0].setOpacity(val/100);
                                                                                                                                         }},
                                                                                                                                        style: 'position:absolute; left:135px;'
                                                                                                                                        }), 
                                                                                                            new Ext.form.Checkbox({
                                                                                                                                        title: extjs_gui_products_forecast_checkbox_title,
                                                                                                                                        id: 'forecast_checkbox_extjs',
                                                                                                                                        boxLabel: extjs_gui_products_forecast_checkbox_label,
                                                                                                                                        inputValue: extjs_gui_products_forecast_checkbox_label,
                                                                                                                                        listeners: {
                                                                                                                                            check: addForecastLayer
                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                    }),";
                                                }
                                                                                                        //this condition controls whether or not the summation button is included in the javascript of the GUI
                                                                                                        if($sumButton==="true"){

                                                                                                                                echo "
                                                                                                                                //TOFINISH
                                                                                                                                new Ext.Slider({
                                                                                                                                        width: 125,
                                                                                                                                        value: 73,
                                                                                                                                        listeners: {
                                                                                                                                            change: function(summationSlider, val) {
                                                                                                                                                map.getLayersByName(openlayers_wms_layer_summation)[0].setOpacity(val/100);
                                                                                                                                         }},
                                                                                                                                        style: 'position:absolute; left:135px;'
                                                                                                                                        }), 
                                                                                                                                new Ext.form.Checkbox({
                                                                                                                                                            title: extjs_gui_products_sum_checkbox_title,
                                                                                                                                                            id: 'sum_checkbox_extjs',
                                                                                                                                                            boxLabel: extjs_gui_products_sum_checkbox_label,
                                                                                                                                                            inputValue: extjs_gui_products_sum_checkbox_label,
                                                                                                                                                            listeners: {
                                                                                                                                                                check: addSummationLayer
                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                        })";

                                                                                                        }

                                                                                echo "
                                                                                                ]
                                                                            }),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like it's less to do with your slider width, and more to do with the parent panel.

Your code doesn't have anything where you're setting the width for the parent panel.

Try that, and see what happens.

(try to clean up the code a little - it's hard to see what's going on, since it's indented so far to the right).

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed a good idea. I changed my bar to be a fixed width instead of relative. The problem was that it was set as 20% width, so my bar was perfect when opening the website in full screen but not ok at all in smaller window (this is why FireFox loaded it in a weird way, this is really lame of me not to see it before). Fixing it a bit larger is perfect. I tested on a couple of browsers and screen size, and even on Windows/Linux, all is great. Thanks a lot.